# Parameter T-SQL stored procedure pass to Where clause only when specified

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am writing a T-SQL stored procedure. I want to "set" a variable so that if 
a parameter, it gets passed into the `where` clause (naturally).

But if nothing is specified for that parameter, I don't want this passed to
the `where` clause.

The reason is the default list is too long for me to specify.

How do I do this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Example
    (@CompanyCode AS NVARCHAR(100) = NULL)
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        .....
    FROM 
        TableX
    WHERE 
        (@CompanyCode IS NOT NULL AND Company = @CompandyCode)
        OR 
        --  Does this work?
        (@CompanyCode IS NULL)
```

Comment: First, your procedure cannot "know" the code executing your procedure did not "pass a parameter". For example, the procedure cannot know if the calling code actually passed NULL as your parameter or if it did not provide any value for the parameter and the db engine supplied the default value. Be careful what you assume. Erland has extensive discussion of [optional parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write:

```
Company = @CompandyCode OR @CompanyCode IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that should work.

```
WHERE @companyCode IS NULL OR (@companyCode IS NOT NULL AND Company = @companyCode)
```